# Error When Parsing MWS Boto Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-mws

With boto one is able to very easily parse data retrieved using `boto.mws.connection` and  `list_orders`  and isolate a specific piece of data such as an order number:

```
from boto.mws.connection import MWSConnection

merchantId = 'XXXXXXXXXXX' 
marketplaceId = 'XXXXXXXXXXX' 
accessKeyId = 'XXXXXXXXXXX' 
secretKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXX' 

mws = MWSConnection(accessKeyId, secretKey, Merchant=merchantId) 

# ListMatchingProducts
a = mws.list_orders(CreatedAfter='2018-05-24T12:00:00Z', MarketplaceId = [marketplaceId])
# retrieve order number within parsed response
a_orderid = a.ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order[0].AmazonOrderId
print(a_orderid)
```

Output amazon order number:

```
123-456789-123456
```

Conversely, if one wants to parse and isolate specific data using the `get_matching_product_for_id` operation, lets say to get the corresponding ASIN for a specific EAN product ID:

```
# GetMatchingProductForId (retrieving product info using EAN code)
b = mws.get_matching_product_for_id(MarketplaceId=marketplaceId,IdType="EAN",IdList=["5705260045710"])
# retrieve ASIN for product within result
b_asin = b.GetMatchingProductForIdResult.Products.Product.MarketplaceASIN
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\API_Amazon_get_matching_product_for_id.py", line 20, in <module>
    b_asin = b.GetMatchingProductForIdResult.Products.Product.MarketplaceASIN
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Products'
```

Can anyone figure out why? Or is there a better way to parse `boto.mws.connection` responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in you Error message. I haven't used boto in a while but without even trying to run your example you can tell the problem is here:

```
b_asin = b.GetMatchingProductForIdResult.Products.Product.MarketplaceASIN
```

The error says:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Products'
```

working backwards we can tell that python is trying to access an attribute called `Products` but the object is a list.

So `b.GetMatchingProductForIdResult` is a list. Try `print`ing it and see what you get. Iterate over it and print the elements or print the dir of the first element to see the attributes of each.

```
print(dir(b.GetMatchingProductForIdResult[0]))
```

The Traceback is your friend, learn it, love it, live it.

Now to MWS specifically:

Amazon provides an xsd file that describes the response [found here](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/ProductsAPI_Response.xsd). This should tell you exactly what you're dealing with. More generally it describes the elements [here](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html).

Comment: You are bang on. I actually just looked up the error and am starting to realise that I'm trying to encode a whole list as one, when I should be trying each element one by one. This is what the error is telling me. Will revert with detailed solution once I figure it out.

Comment: @AlexB I added some links to info which will save you a lot of headaches later. I remember creating a large project which interacted with amazon's marketplace before they provided these xsd right in the docs, it is pure gold

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! Shame boto seems to be dropping mws in boto3. Do you recommend any alternatives to achieve mws to python connection?

Comment: @AlexB I used boto in that project a year ago and I explored some other alternatives but boto is tested and scrutinized as is proven by their issues tracker in github and the stars (although those people starring it may not be using the MWS module). Moreover, the MWS module is pretty simple, coupled with the fact that when I last checked (about a year ago) amazon hadn't changed its API in a long time. I think I subclassed the boto mws class to make it work the way I wanted. If you want to discuss it further you can start a chat.

Comment: Yes please. If you could start a chat that would be great as I have a few questions regarding subclass.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the answer as @Verbal_Kint pointed out. Using my example above one can retrieve the ASIN by digging down the tree and treating attributes as lists when needed. I haven't quite figured out why some attributes are lists and some aren't but at this stage a quick trial and error enabled me to find the solution:

```
b_asin = b.GetMatchingProductForIdResult[0].Products.Product[0].Identifiers.MarketplaceASIN.ASIN
print(b_asin)
```

Comment: room started https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172301/room-for-verbal-kint-and-alex-b